# Eclipse MARS linux environment usage on include paths

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I´m using Eclipse Mars C++ and  I need to referente a linux environment variable on my include path.

So, we have in Ubuntu prompt:

```
$ printenv | grep WORKSPACE
WORKSPACE_HOME=/home/myself/projectA
```

In Eclipse:

***Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Includes->Include Paths:***

[image]

When compiling, I´m getting:

```
g++ -std=c++0x _IORKSPACE_HOME/includes
```

Why is not Eclipse expanding the `$WORKSPACE_HOME` ?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`"${WORKSPACE_HOME}/includes"` should work.

Comment: No, it does not work. Result: `-I{ORKSPACE}/includes`